# Resultados Repetidos en C++

Tags: c++

He creado un código en el que registro cierta cantidad de jugadores de fútbol y al finalizar se imprimen sus datos, pero estos se repiten de acuerdo al ultimo jugador registrado. Este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

system("color E0");

int CantidadJugadores = 0;
char NombresJugadores[50], PosicionJugadores[50], ExpulsionesJugadores[10], NumeroJugadores[10], GolesJugadores[10], FaltasJugadores[10];
cout<<"///////////////////INICIO DEL REGISTRO DE JUGADORES///////////////////////\n";
cout<<"Inserta la cantidad de jugadores \n";
cin>>CantidadJugadores;
char* registros[CantidadJugadores][6]; // VECTOR DE JUGADORES
for(int indice=0; indice < CantidadJugadores; indice++)
{
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"\tJugador Numero "<<indice+1;
        cout<<"\nInserta el nombre del jugador \n";
        cin>>NombresJugadores;
        registros[ indice ][0] = NombresJugadores;

        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Inserta el numero del jugador \n";
        cin>>NumeroJugadores;
        registros[ indice ][1] = NumeroJugadores;

        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Inserta la posicion del jugador \n";
        cin>>PosicionJugadores;
        registros[ indice ][2] = PosicionJugadores;

        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Inserta la cantidad de goles del jugador \n";
        cin>>GolesJugadores;
        registros[ indice ][3] = GolesJugadores;

        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Inserta la cantidad de faltas del jugador \n";
        cin>>FaltasJugadores;
        registros[ indice ][4] = FaltasJugadores;

        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Inserta la cantidad de expulsiones del jugador \n";
        cin>>ExpulsionesJugadores;
        registros[ indice ][5] = ExpulsionesJugadores;

        cout<<"\n===================Jugador: "<<indice+1<<"===================\n";
}
cout<<"\n///////////////////FIN DEL REGISTRO DE JUGADORES////////////////////////\n";
system("PAUSE");
system("cls");

system("color 1F");
cout<<"/////////////////// Estos Son Los Datos /////////////////// \n"<<endl;
int indice=0;
while( indice < CantidadJugadores ){ 
    cout<<"\tJugador Numero "<<indice+1<<endl;
    cout<<"\nNombre: "<< registros[indice][0] <<endl;
    cout<<"Numero de Jugador: "<<registros[indice][1] <<endl;
    cout<<"Posicion: "<< registros[indice][2] <<endl;
    cout<<"Goles: "<< registros[indice][3] <<endl;
    cout<<"Faltas: "<< registros[indice][4] <<endl;
    cout<<"Expulsiones: "<< registros[indice][5] <<endl;
    cout<<"============================================="<<endl;
    indice++;
}
return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

En C++ **no es legal** usar variables para declarar arrays:

```
int CantidadJugadores = 0;
cin>>CantidadJugadores;
char* registros[CantidadJugadores][6];
```

Esta característica se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y **no** es una característica estándar. Si bien algunos compiladores la soportan no es conveniente su uso ya que aparte de no ser portable, no se garantiza su funcionalidad en todos los casos.

Para gestionar este tipo de arrays tienes que acudir a la memoria dinánica o usar un contenedor de la STL.

Por otro lado, tu vector de jugadores:

```
char* registros[CantidadJugadores][6]; // VECTOR DE JUGADORES
```

Es una matriz de punteros. Es decir, cada posición (por ejemplo `registros[0][0]`), es un puntero. Dado que cuando haces las asignaciones usas **la misma variable** todo el rato, lo que consigues es que los diferentes registros apunten a la misma posición de memoria. Dicho gráficamente:

```
registros[0][0] = NombresJugadores;
registros[1][0] = NombresJugadores;
registros[2][0] = NombresJugadores;
```

La solución más simple aquí sería usar `std::string` en vez de punteros a `char`:

```
std::string registros[01][6];
```

Aunque yo personalmente te sugeriría crear una estructura de datos:

```
struct Jugador
{
  std::string nombre;
  int numero;
  std::string posicion;
  int goles;
  int faltas;
  int expulsiones;
};

cin>>CantidadJugadores;
Jugador * jugadores = new Jugador[CantidadJugadores];

// ...

cout << "\tJugador Numero "<<indice+1;
cout << "\nInserta el nombre del jugador \n";
cin >> registros[indice].nombre;

cout << "Inserta el numero del jugador \n";
cin >> registros[indice].numero;

cout << "Inserta la posicion del jugador \n";
cin >> registros[indice].posicion;

// ...

delete[] jugadores;
```